# Limiting multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I'm running a python script on a server shared with other people.

The script is N times on N different files by a multiprocessing.Pool, which executes K processes at a time.

At the beginning of this script, there is a function call that uses multiple cores.

I don't want to overload the server, so I want to use at most K cores. But when this function is called K times, you can image the result.

What can I do?

I'm using the function map on a list of inputs, which are the N external files.

Comment: The first argument to the `multiprocessing.Pool` constructor is the number of jobs (processes) it can run in parallel at the same time. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: Sizing is something of a dark art. If that function is relatively small compared to the rest of the processing in your worker, then you could likely just run and not worry about it - operating systems are okay with spikeyness. You could also experiment with placing a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) or [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore) around the function so that others pause when it fires.

Comment: @martineau I need to limit the number of cores. The problem is that this function F apparently is running as well on multiple cores. For example, if I run on 10 cores, each process is going to use 5 other cores. This makes a total of 50 cores. Which is almost all the cores on the server. I cannot use all of them!

Comment: @tdelaney I forgot about locks. It's been a while since my "distributed computing" course :D I will try it. Put in the answers.